# How to create Listview with Load more and Pull to refresh in MAUI?

Tags: listview, maui, lazy-loading, collectionview, pull-to-refresh

I am new to MAUI. I want to create one list with Load more and Pull to Refresh functionality.

When user reach to end of list, it should provide a loader at bottom and can have callback so we can call API to load the data.

Similar to load more when user drag the list bottom when it reach to top, want to show loader at top and callback method so we can call API for first page and reset data.

Any help will be appreciated. Please let me know if you want more details.

I have checked syncfusion library but found it does have only PullTorefresh part. Please correct me if you find something different.

Comment: Use [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data?view=net-maui-8.0#load-data-incrementally) instead

Comment: It provides load more pull to refresh?

Comment: Yes.  Please take the time to read the docs

Comment: CollectionView supports incremental data virtualization as the user scrolls by using RemainingItemsThreshold and RemainingItemsThresholdReached property. Sepecifically, you can refer to [Load data incrementally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data?view=net-maui-8.0#load-data-incrementally).